# android - if phone has not external sd_card memory

Tags: android

some phones did not support external sd_card , what this function **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();**  return in this case ?

Comment: My guess is MEDIA_UNKNOWN, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will usually display an external storage directory path like "/mnt/sdcard" or "/sdcard" or "/storage/0". This function has nothing to do with removable media like micro sd card.

Answer (score 0):

It will return `MEDIA_UNKNOWN`

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#MEDIA_UNKNOWN):

> Unknown storage state, such as when a path isn't backed by known storage media.